# Was the deposed Pakistani PM Nawaz Sharif working for India?

Tags: india, pakistan

The former PM of Pakistan, Nawaz Sharif, who was banned from Politics for life by the Supreme Court of Pakistan is widely alleged as a guy who was working to uphold Indian interest in Pakistan.

- [“Mujhay kyun nikala?”](https://nation.com.pk/26-May-2018/597228?show=blocks?unique_ID=636575940403384925)
- [Resolutions in Pakistan assemblies for treason against Sharif](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/international/world-news/resolutions-in-pakistan-assemblies-for-treason-against-sharif/articleshow/64175499.cms)
- [Nawaz, the ‘traitor’](https://dailytimes.com.pk/240938/nawaz-the-traitor/)
- [Disqualified P.M. Nawaz Sharif’s Indian Connections Proved](http://kashmirwatch.com/disqualified-p-m-nawaz-sharifs-indian-connections-proved/)
- [Nawaz Sharif- traitor or trader?](https://www.globalvillagespace.com/nawaz-sharif-traitor-or-trader/)
- ['Brand him a traitor', anti-Sharif chorus grows in Pakistan](https://www.indiatoday.in/india/story/-brand-him-a-traitor-anti-sharif-chorus-grows-in-pakistan-after-mumbai-attack-comments-1233227-2018-05-14)

On August 13, 2011, Nawaz Sharif was seen ([Part1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjxWeUT_DKk), [Part2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KF0O1BS42fU)) praising former PM of India Atal Bihari Vajpayee, and saying that Kargil War was a backstab by Pakistan Army to India.

On 29 December 2015, [it was reported by newspapers](https://www.dawn.com/news/1229419) that a large number of entourages of visiting PM Modi entered Pakistan without a visa.

Nawaz was also [accused of keeping silent](https://thediplomat.com/2016/05/pakistan-nawaz-sharif-in-the-eye-of-the-storm/) on the arrest of the captured alleged Indian spy [Kulbhushan Jadav](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2017/12/pakistan-india-spar-spy-kulbhushan-jadhav-171227074224491.html).

On 27 April 2017, Indian businessman [Sajjan Jindal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sajjan_Jindal), who is known for being close to Prime Minister Narendra Modi, [met Nawaz Sharif](https://tribune.com.pk/story/1395521/pm-hot-water-secret-meeting-indian-tycoon/) in his Murre resort where he was allowed to [violate](https://tribune.com.pk/story/1395560/jindal-violated-visa-meet-nawaz-murree/) visa terms.

On May 12, 2018, Nawaz Sharif took media by storm when [**he remarked**](https://www.dawn.com/news/1407192) that Pakistan Army was behind 2006's Mumbai's terror attack.

[According to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xlWMN1WbR0) the former president and the army chief Gen Pervez Musharraf, Nawaz Sharif made Pakistan Army retreat from an advantageous position during the Kargil War in 1999 and hence accepted a political and military defeat from India.

**Was the deposed Pakistani PM Nawaz Sharif working for Indian interest in Pakistan?**

Comment: Since this is a question about an individual's motivations (i.e. were his actions motivated by a desire to benefit India), please see https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/politics-beliefs-and-motivations-questions-should-not-be-allowed-here and its answers.